# Explicit CDF associated to Gamma PDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let the distribution function of $X$ for $x>0$ be:

$$F(x) = 1 - \sum_0^3   \frac{x^ke^{-x}}{k!}$$

what is the density function of $X$ for $x > 0$?

---

This is what I'm thinking:

$$  \frac{x^0e^{-x}}{1} + \frac{x^1e^{-x}}{1} + \frac{x^2e^{-x}}{2} + \frac{x^3e^{-x}}{6} $$

and this looks like the beginning of a series expansion... and I know one thing we can do with series is try to differentiate or integrate.

And since we are going from cdf to pdf I think that means we want to differentiate (so maybe I didnt need to actually plug those numbers in above)

So: $$ \frac d{dx}(1-\sum_0^3   \frac{x^ke^{-x}}{k!}) = 
$$
I don't know but here goes nothin...:$$-( kx^{k-1}e^{-x}-x^ke^{-x} ) =$$
I think thats the derivative of the numerator anyway. Now I'm seeing k! as a constant no matter what. So that denominator can just be left there til after? I guess the summation can't just disappear for no good reason either so:   $$-\sum_0^3 \frac {kx^{k-1}e^{-x}-x^ke^{-x}}{k!} $$

**OK so my reasoning  about the why i THOUGHT it is discrete is because I saw the summation and thought 'ooh, discrete' but it's actually increasing the k by 1, not the x, and the problem states x>0.**

So lemme try this again: $$-e^{-x}\sum_0^3 \frac {kx^{k-1}-x^k}{k!} =  $$
$$e^{-x}\sum_0^3 \frac {x^k-kx^{k-1}}{k!} =  $$

so now I can use my summation knowledge!...

Ooh wow, so this is **interesting**, the first 4 terms: $$ (1) + (x-1) + (\frac12 x^2-x) + (\frac{x^3}6-\frac12 x^2)$$

so each successive term is negating the previous 2nd highest power's term.

Therefore: $$ (\frac16)e^{-x}x^3 $$

phew! But super interesting! What is this sort of series called? I like its style (I haven't done much with series)

Comment: At first I noticed it is discrete. Also, the sum = 1 which makes sense being that it is a cdf. Accidentally pressed 'enter'.. im still writing

Comment: and distribution functions is saying the probability added up to this point is... ARGH why does alt+enter not just put me to a new line. Sorry about the multiple comments, I'll continue writing in the next one

Comment: shift+enter lets you write in a new line.

Note that the new lines don't appear in the final comment, however.

Comment: Are you sure this is discrete?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom hmm... well now that you say that. I guess I was thinking discrete because I saw the summation notation. Now that I think about it, the Sigma is for the k!, and x>0 so then x is continuous from 0 to \inf ... hmmm

Comment: As for the "$1-$": note that any cdf defined over $x>0$ has to have a limit of $1$ as $x \to \infty$

Comment: Ooh! Wait! I think I thought of something! dont tell me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every nonnegative integer $n$, the density $f$ defined on $x\gt0$ by $f(x)=\frac1{n!}x^n\mathrm e^{-x}$ is the PDF of the [gamma distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) $(n+1,1)$. Your case is when $n=3$. The parameter $n$ could be any real number $n\gt-1$ provided $n!$ is replaced by $\Gamma(n+1)$.